# tabHostで構成された画面のTextViewを、再表示ごとに更新させる方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, android-fragments

tabHostで構成された画面のTextViewを、再表示ごとに更新させる方法を教えて下さい。

詳細：
　お世話なっております。
　
　現在、tabHost（３画面構成）で作られた各画面に、SharedPreferencesのデータをTextViewで表示させるアプリを制作しております。
　いざ、制作してみると、onStart()内でデータを読み出し、findViewByIdでTextViewを指定し表示させることができたのですが、他の画面に移動し元の画面に戻ると、TextViewの表示が消えてし空白になってしまいます。
　アプリの動作上、毎回、画面表示ごとに最新のSharedPreferencesデータを読み出し、表示する動作にしたいため、色々試しているのですが、再表示の方法がわからず困っております。

不思議なのが、Logで確認したところonViewCreated()のsetTextが実行されているようなのに反映されていないことです。勉強しているところですが、もしかしてsetTextが一回しか実行できない何らかの規則があるでしょうか？または、Fragmentのライフサイクルの関係なのでしょうか？
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

補足：
現在、サンプルのslidingtabsbasicを改良し、SlidingTabsBasicFragment.javaのinstantiateItem内にSharedPreferencesをsetTextを置くことで画面遷移でもTextが空白にならず、データの変更もできるようになりました。しかし、今回はタブクリックで画面遷移したい動きが希望なので、このまま使用できません。
tabHostを使用し、instantiateItemのような動きを可能となる方法をご存知の方がおりましたら、アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 無事、自己解決いたしました。 　
解決方法を記載させていただきます。 　 
メソッドを作りその中でTextViewの指定と表示を行うことで望みの動作になりました。 　
お世話をお掛けしました